# Limit models to select

Tags: sql, database, cakephp, models

I have a database table called Event which in CakePHP has its relationships coded to like so:

```
var $belongsTo = array('Sport');
var $hasOne = array('Result', 'Point', 'Writeup', 'Timetable', 'Photo');
```

Now am doing a query and only want to pull out Sport, Point, and Timetable

Which would result in me retrieving Sports, Events, Points, and Timetable.

Reason for not pulling everything is due the results having 17000+ rows.

Is there a way to only select those tables using:

```
$this->Event->find('all');
```

I have had a look at the API but can't see how its done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set recursive to -1 in your app_model and only pull the things you require. never use recursive of 2 and http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable is awesome.

just $this->Event->find('all', array('contain' => array()));

if you do the trick of recursive as -1 in app_model, this is not needed, if would just be find('all') like you have

Comment: So if I do 'contain' and define the tables? or tables and fields? Will that give me the desire affect?

Comment: i also doubt that those are all HAS ONE relations^^

Comment: what does the relation type have to do with it? containable works on everything.